# epoch time to Date with current year

Tags: java, datetime, epoch

```
String mytime = "5177706";

long epoch = Long.parseLong( mytime );

Date expiry = new Date( epoch * 1000 );
```

When I convert epoch time to date, the result is

> Mon Mar 02 05:45:06 SGT 1970

Cause of epoch time, the year is 1970, although the day and month of the answer is desired result.

**How can I convert the year to current year as a output eg. Mon Mar 02 05:45:06 SGT 2012 ?**

Comment: The epoch you are showing is of year 1970. Java conversion is correct. Your epoch time is old. Current year's epoch starts with `133`.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you just want to do this:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(expiry);
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2012);
Date expiryThisYear = cal.getTime();
```

Raises some interesting questions about how you came to have 517706 as an input in the first place, but the world is a strange place sometimes :)

Answer (score 0):

The following code adds the `epoch`, 5177706 seconds, to January 1st of the current year, which is January 1st, 2012 00:00:00:000 GMT.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String mytime = "5177706";
    long epoch = Long.parseLong(mytime);

    // Get January 1st of the current year in GMT.
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.JANUARY);
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    // Convert epoch to milliseconds and add to January 1st of the current year.
    Date expiry = new Date(calendar.getTime().getTime() + epoch * 1000);

    // Output the expiry date in Asia/Singapore (SGT) time.
    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
    format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Singapore"));
    System.out.println(format.format(expiry));
}
```

The above code outputs `Thu Mar 01 06:15:06 SGT 2012`. The month, day, and time differ from the expected `Mar 02 05:45:06 SGT` for the following reasons:

- [Singapore Standard Time (SGT)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singapore_Standard_Time) changed from UTC+07:30 to UTC+08:00 on December 31st 1981, so add 30 minutes to the time:

  `Mar 02 05:45:06 SGT` + 30 minutes = `Mar 02 06:15:06 SGT`.
- 2012 is a leap year, so subtract a day:

  `Mar 02 06:15:06 SGT` - 1 day = `Mar 01 06:15:06 SGT`

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear (sounds like some weird HW problem). Anyway, you just have to add the time elapsed since the date you provided (in milliseconds).

1. `msOriginal` is the date you provided in ms.
2. `msElapsed` is total ms elapsed since 1970. This is equal to `2012 - 1970 = 42` years.
3. `msElapsedLeapYears` is the total leapyear days elapsed. If you look at the wiki article, [List of leap years](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_leap_years) you can see that there were 11 years. So you have to account for 11 days.

The sum of the above 3 fields gives you the result you are looking for. Notice, the dates don't fall on the same day (March 1st is not a Sunday in 2012). If you'd like the day to be the same, it needs to be 2015 (45 years). Basically, the number of days elapsed mod 7 needs to be 0 for the date to fall on the same day.

This sample code is done in groovy so the syntax is slightly different from regular java.

```
long epoch = 5177706l;
Calendar current = Calendar.getInstance();
current.setTimeInMillis(epoch*1000);
println current.getTime();
long msOriginal = (epoch*1000);
long msElapsed = 42l*365*24l*3600*1000;
long msElapsedLeapYears = 11l*24*3600*1000;
current.setTimeInMillis(msOriginal+msElapsed+msElapsedLeapYears);
println current.getTime();
```

Result:

```
Sun Mar 01 16:15:06 CST 1970
Thu Mar 01 16:15:06 CST 2012
```